# Splitting out a field in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have searched around and can not find much on this topic (maybe bad search terms :). I have a table, Protopayload.resource, that gets Apache logging information. As a result the field I am interested in contains multiple values that I need to search against. The field is formatted in a php URL style. 
i.e.

```
/?id=13242134123&ver=12&os_bits=64&os_type=mac&lng=EN
```

This makes all searches end up with really long regexes to get data. Then join statements to combine data.

Example search to combine mac/win stats

```
SELECT
  t1.date, t1.wincount, COALESCE(t2.maccount, 0) AS maccount
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS date,
    INTEGER(COUNT(protoPayload.resource)) AS wincount
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(tablename, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ))
  WHERE
    (REGEXP_MATCH(protoPayload.resource, r'ver=[11,12'))
    AND protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'os=win' GROUP BY date ) t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS date,
    INTEGER(COUNT(protoPayload.resource)) AS maccount
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(tablename, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ))
  WHERE
    (REGEXP_MATCH(protoPayload.resource, r'cv=[p,m][17,16,15,14]'))
    AND protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'os=mac' GROUP BY date ) t2
ON
  t1.date = t2.date
ORDER BY t1.date
```

What I was thinking was to use similar regex searches. Create a new table. Then save the data to a new table with relation fields. Then fix future logging so it logs to the table correctly.

My questions are this valid solution, or is there a much easier way to accomplish this in Google BigQuery? Is there a better way to transform the data?
Thanks again for any input!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So essentially your question is does Google BigQuery provide an easy way to parse URLs?  I'm not a GBQ expert, but in general I would say your approach seems fine.  That said, I think you're more likely to get an answer if you were to provide an alternative and phrase your question as "which one is better: a or b?"

Answer (score 5):

You can use a SQL function to parse the key-value pairs into an array, which will generally be faster than using JavaScript. For example,

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ParseKeys(queryString STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>> AS (
  (SELECT
     ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
       entry[OFFSET(0)] AS key,
       entry[OFFSET(1)] AS value))
   FROM (
     SELECT SPLIT(pairString, '=') AS entry
     FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(queryString, r'/\?(.*)'), '&')) AS pairString)
   )
);
SELECT ParseKeys('/?foo=bar&baz=2');
```

Now you can build on this with a function that pivots the keys into struct fields:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetAttributes(queryString STRING) AS (
  (SELECT AS STRUCT
     MAX(IF(key = 'id', CAST(value AS INT64), NULL)) AS id,
     MAX(IF(key = 'ver', CAST(value AS INT64), NULL)) AS ver,
     MAX(IF(key = 'os_bits', CAST(value AS INT64), NULL)) AS os_bits,
     MAX(IF(key = 'os_type', value, NULL)) AS os_type,
     MAX(IF(key = 'lng', value, NULL)) AS lng
   FROM UNNEST(ParseKeys(queryString)))
);
```

Putting everything together, you can try out the `GetAttributes` function with some sample input:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ParseKeys(queryString STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>> AS (
  (SELECT
     ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(
       entry[OFFSET(0)] AS key,
       entry[OFFSET(1)] AS value))
   FROM (
     SELECT SPLIT(pairString, '=') AS entry
     FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(queryString, r'/\?(.*)'), '&')) AS pairString)
   )
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION GetAttributes(queryString STRING) AS (
  (SELECT AS STRUCT
     MAX(IF(key = 'id', CAST(value AS INT64), NULL)) AS id,
     MAX(IF(key = 'ver', CAST(value AS INT64), NULL)) AS ver,
     MAX(IF(key = 'os_bits', CAST(value AS INT64), NULL)) AS os_bits,
     MAX(IF(key = 'os_type', value, NULL)) AS os_type,
     MAX(IF(key = 'lng', value, NULL)) AS lng
   FROM UNNEST(ParseKeys(queryString)))
);
SELECT url, GetAttributes(url).*
FROM UNNEST(['/?id=13242134123&ver=12&os_bits=64&os_type=mac&lng=EN',
             '/?id=2343645745&ver=15&os_bits=32&os_type=linux&lng=FR']) AS url;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Javascript UDFs for maximum flexibility. They will be slower than a pure SQL solution, but you'll be able to code around its limitations.

For example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parse(query STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<id STRING, ver STRING, os_bits STRING, os_type STRING, lng STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  function parseQueryString(query) {
      // http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10396
      var  map   = {};
      query.replace(/([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)(?:&+|$)/g, function(match, key, value) {
          (map[key] = map[key] || []).push(value);
      });
      return map;
  }

  return parseQueryString(query)  

""";


WITH urls AS
  (SELECT 'id=13242134123&ver=12&os_bits=64&os_type=mac&lng=EN' query
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'id=13242134124&ver=12&os_bits=64&os_type=mac&lng=EN1&lng=EN2' query
)


SELECT query, parse(query) as parsed
FROM urls;.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see few issues in the query in your question
1. looks like regexp is not correct and will not capture what you expect
2. query is heavily over-engineered and can be quite simplified

Below is to address above points

```
SELECT
  DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS date,
  SUM(REGEXP_MATCH(protoPayload.resource, r'ver=(11|12)\b') 
      AND protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'os_type=win'
  ) AS wincount,
  SUM(REGEXP_MATCH(protoPayload.resource, r'cv=(p|m)(17|16|15|14)\b') 
      AND protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'os_type=mac'
  ) AS maccount
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(tablename, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY'),
                                  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ))
GROUP BY date
```

Please note: you query in question is written with BigQuery Legacy SQL, so I keep my answer in same dialect